# Projecting a cut onto a surface around a sphere

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I'm looking to cut a shape into the surface of a sphere using a 3D curve. I have a curve wrapped onto the sphere. I do not want to knife-project because the shape needs to wrap around the sides in a way that goes past the ortho view
[image: Curve bending around a sphere]

The task feels intuitive; from the "normal up" direction towards "normal down" I want to project a cut between the curve and the sphere. But I do not know a method for this.

Comment: Just a workaround ... Curve to Mesh > Extrude > Scale, Sphere - add Solidify and Boolean > Difference (Curve), Visual Geometry to Mesh, Merge by Distance.

Comment: ... THere is also Intersect Knife, but it expects  overlapping faces, that I'm not sure if Curve to Mesh and Shrinkwrap generates.

Answer (score 0):

Working from vklidu's idea; just a workaround, but good enough:
[image: A ring cut into a sphere]

I've converted to mesh, extruded out and in, done a bit of scaling to make it match the "approximate" normal direction, then added a Solidify to the ring, and Boolean differenced it with the sphere (which also has a thickness modifier on it).

At this point, I can apply everything and clean up a bunch. It gets there.

Comment: You could extrude one direction and scale to center of sphere ... solidify you should use to sphere (not curve) like that you can get single cut in mesh = less cleaning :)